# MimeMessage.setContent() takes filename which contains html code

Tags: java, html, email

I have a html.txt file which has html code in it. I want my java code to send a mail as below:

```
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.addHeader("Content-type", "text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
msg.addHeader("format", "flowed");
msg.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abc@xyz.com"));
msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
msg.setContent(body, "text/HTML");
```

I want the above body to read the html.txt file and send the mail  in html format. How to do this?

Comment: you need to parse the file content to the string .In your case to the string `body`

Answer (score 0):

You shall read your `html.txt` file into a `string`

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("<path to html.txt>"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        sb.append(scanner.nextLine());
    }

    String body = sb.toString();
```

and then pass that to the `setContent` method

```
   msg.setContent(body, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Please Note that your `html.txt` file should not contain `<html>`, `<head>` or `<body>` tags.

Hope this helps.